# How to tell Vite to only build a specific component in library mode?

Tags: vue.js, vite

I have a Vue project that is able to load other Vue components bundled as .mjs files. I want to develop all those pluggable components inside a repository but instead of distributing all pluggable components in a single build I want to tell Vite which component to build. If that works I don't need to think about dealing with a Monorepo, Multirepo or something else.

After creating the library project I thought about organizing each plugin into a separate folder in the src directory

```
.
└── src
    ├── textWithBlueBackground
    |   ├── index.ts ( importing "TextWithBlueBackground" and exporting as "Renderer" )
    |   └── TextWithBlueBackground.vue
    └── textWithRedBackground
        ├── index.ts ( importing "TextWithRedBackground" and exporting as "Renderer" )
        └── TextWithRedBackground.vue
```

The problem is that I need to switch to [library mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode) but I don't know what to pass in there

```
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.ts"), // this is wrong
      name: "Renderer",
      fileName: "renderer",
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["vue"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: "Vue",
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

After fixing that... Is it possible to tell Vite ( via CLI flag ) to only build a specific sub directory? E.g.

> vite build ./src/{folderName}

If that's not possible I could create an index.ts in src

```
import { Renderer as TextWithBlueBackground } from "./textWithBlueBackground";
import { Renderer as TextWithRedBackground } from "./textWithRedBackground";

export { TextWithBlueBackground, TextWithRedBackground }
```

but how can I tell Vite to only build a specific component then?

The generated .mjs file should only contain the desired component, preferably as "Renderer" but I think the component name should be fine too.

Comment: You need to specify multiple entry points, one per "plugin", it's documented https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode

Comment: Yes you are right, I could do `entry: [resolve(__dirname, "./src/textWithBlueBackground/index.ts"), resolve(__dirname, "./src/textWithRedBackground/index.ts")]` but then it generates multiple renderer files... It was not possible for me to assign an array to `lib` to give them unique names ... do you have any ideas?

Comment: I also tried a dictionary `entry: { textWithBlueBackground: resolve(__dirname, "./src/textWithBlueBackground/index.ts"), textWithRedBackground: resolve(__dirname, "./src/textWithRedBackground/index.ts")},`